# Instruction "int 3" appears whilst running windbg. Why?

Tags: debugging, x86, windbg

While doing crash analysis, I encountered bellow instructions.

```
74553ef7 50              push    eax
74553ef8 e81ba0ffff      call    MSVCR90!CxxThrowException (7454df18) 
74553efd cc              int     3 
74553efe cc              int     3
74553eff cc              int     3
74553f00 cc              int     3
74553f01 cc              int     3
74553f02 cc              int     3
```

While running windbg, I found running stoped on `int 3` instruction.
As far as I know `int 3` instruction is `trap to debugger` exception, which stands for the `breakpoint`.

But the thing is:

1. I've not set any bp on windbg.
2. So I checked debugger's *default bp*, and there're no enabled exception handler of windbg like *below*.

```
0:009> sx
vcpp - Visual C++ exception - second-chance break - handled
 wkd - Wake debugger - second-chance break - not handled
 wob - WOW64 breakpoint - second-chance break - handled
 wos - WOW64 single step exception - second-chance break - handled
```

***Question:***

1. Is `int 3` set by windbg? if so, why?
2. Is `int 3` originally exist on binary image? If so, why compiler inserts this instruction?

Comment: 0xCC is the [pattern for uninitialized memory in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: *Is int 3 originally exist on binary image?*  Yes, but you could check that yourself with a disassembler, if you aren't sure you can trust your debugger not to be showing you a munged copy of the code.

Comment: I believe this q/a may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090317/visual-c-appends-0xcc-int3-bytes-at-the-end-of-functions

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes I found `cc` exist in disassembly ether. I also checked the links that all of you mentioned on comments. However there's a difference in my situation. This `cc` is code(NOT an uninitialized variable) and is executed during runtime(NOT a just padding being used for function alignment). So is that mean compiler insert 0xcc INTENTIONALLY to EXECUTE IT during runtime. Is that right?

Comment: No, MSVC uses `CC` for alignment padding *between functions*, where it won't execute.  NOP for padding *inside* functions to align loops.  Both of these are totally separate from its debug-mode poisoning of uninitialized stack and malloc with the same bit-pattern.  @phuclv linked a Q&A about `CC` as data, but the ones I used as duplicates are about `CC` as code.